# How to apply LIMIT only to parent rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my Postgres database I have a table that holds a simply hierarchy, something like this:

```
id | parent_id
---------------
```

When an item in the table is a "top-level" item, its `parent_id` is set to `NULL`

However, when I query my table I retrieve the top-level items and the child items that belong to those items. E.g. if there is a single top-level item with two children my query returns three rows. My query is super simple, it looks something like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  my_table
LIMIT
  _limit
OFFSET
  _offset
;
```

When the above returns the three rows, in my business logic I then transform that result into a JSON structure that is then serialized to the client. It looks something like this:

```
items: [
  {
    id: 1,
    parent_id: null,
    items: [
      {
        id: 2,
        parent_id: 1
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        parent_id: 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

However, as you can see my query has `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` for, you guessed it, pagination. The table is quite large and I want to restrict the amount of items that can be requested in a single request.

The problem is that, and continuing to use my single top-level item as an example, if the `LIMIT` is set to `1` then the children of the top-level item will never be returned.

What I am basically looking for is a way to exclude child rows from counting towards the `LIMIT`, or, to expand the `LIMIT` with the total number of child rows found.

Comment: What are you ordering by?  Do the sub-items themselves have children *(or is it always only one level deep)*?  Do you have another table in which the parent id is unique and can be ordered in the same way?  *(To select 'the next X parents' **then** go and look up their descendants?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to do two things:

1. Get the top level entries to include (paginated)
2. Run another query for the descendants of the top level

This is a fully recursive example

```
create table t (id int primary key, parent_id int);

insert into t (id, parent_id) values
  (1, null), (2, null), (3, null), (4, 1),
  (5, 1), (6, 4), (7, 2), (8, 2),
  (9, 8), (10, 3), (11, null), (12, null);


with recursive entries (id, parent_id) as (
  (
   select 
     id, parent_id 
   from t 
   where parent_id is null
   order by id limit 2 -- add offset N here
  ) 
  union all
  (
    select 
      t.id, t.parent_id
    from entries inner join t on (t.parent_id = entries.id) 
  )
) 
select * from entries;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g3G2t3mVo7fBhQa9QCA71P/0

Comment: Thank you! That makes total sense :)